# Selecting the latest record based on DATETIME

Tags: sql-server, select, distinct

I need to select the latest record per memberid by DATETIME.

SAY my table is like this:

```
MemberID    CreatedDate
188         2013-01-31 08:10:15.990
188         2013-01-31 08:10:15.970
188         2013-01-24 19:36:01.840
244         2013-01-24 19:36:01.840
244         2013-01-31 08:10:15.970
244         2013-01-31 08:10:15.980
```

OUT:

188     2013-01-31 08:10:15.990
 244     2013-01-31 08:10:15.980

SQL QUERY to select the latest based on date-Time-milliseconds.

Thank in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried writing anything to get your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is using a ranking function like [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT MemberID, CreatedDate, 
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID 
                                  ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC)
   FROM dbo.TableName  
)
SELECT MemberID, CreatedDate FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

This just returns one record per `MemberID` (the one with the latest `CreatedDate`). If you have multiple latest records an arbitrary is taken. If you want to take all in this case you have to replace `ROW_NUMBER` with `DENSE_RANK`.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for,  you need to group the memberID and Find the max CreatedDate

```
Select memberId, max(CreatedDate) from members
Group By memberId
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this you are looking for.

```
 select memberid,max(createddate)  createddate from Table
    group by memberid
```